# How can I activate GeoSparql in Graphdb?

Tags: sparql, graphdb, geosparql

I looked into the documentation and it is written that we should add
INSERT DATA { _:s geoSparql:enabled "true" . } to the setting in Graphdb to be able to query OpenStreetMap. But I don't understand how or where should I do this.

Here is the instruction: https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/9.4/free/geosparql-support.html#usage
Could you please help me? Thanks.

Update: I added my query here. It works in sophox.org but not in the graphdb.

```
PREFIX osmt: <https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:>
PREFIX osmm: <https://www.openstreetmap.org/meta/> 
PREFIX geoSparql: <http://www.ontotext.com/plugins/geosparql#>


SELECT * {
       ?uni osmt:amenity "university";
       osmt:addr:country   "FR".
}
```

[image]

Comment: what is not clear? Just call this query in the SPARQL interface to your GraphDB repository

Comment: not that I understand how you want o query OSM then - did you load OSM RDF data and if so which one from where?

Comment: I didn't load any data in the GraphDB. I thought it would query the osm like the sophox.org would do.

Comment: what is not clear is that how or where should I write this INSERT DATA?

Comment: Did you setup GraphDB and created a repository? I mean, at some point in time you have to do it for your dataset. And then you have to load OpenStreetMap in RDF format. Querying data is explained here: https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/quick-start-guide.html#query-your-data - in such a SPARQL interface you can also execture `INSERT` statements

Comment: Yes, I have set a repository in Graphdb, which works okay with other queries for which I have updated some RDF files. But for the GeoSPARQL query, I have not uploaded any data in GraphDB. I updated my question with my code.

Comment: I was following this article, and my impression was that GraphDB will automatically query the OSM. When you say that I have to load OSM in RDF format to GraphDB, you mean I have to convert all of the open data that they have into RDF? Or, I have to first query in OSM, and then upload the results     INSERT    into graphDB?

Comment: I added `SERVICE <https://sophox.org/sparql>` after the first curly bracket and it is working perfectly now. Thanks a lot for your guidance.

Comment: ok, then this was a misunderstanding - GeoSPARQL support doesn't load any random external dataset containing geospatial information like the Sophox stuff. It just enables a geospatial index on the locally loaded data, i.e. it creates an efficient search index on polygons and coordinates and then allows for searching inside those polygons or computing distances of points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `SERVICE <https://sophox.org/sparql>` after the first curly bracket and it is working perfectly now.

```
PREFIX osmt: <https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:>
PREFIX osmm: <https://www.openstreetmap.org/meta/> 
PREFIX geoSparql: <http://www.ontotext.com/plugins/geosparql#>


SELECT * {<https://sophox.org/sparql> {
   ?uni osmt:amenity "university";
   osmt:addr:country   "FR".
}}
```